# async/await in try/catch not showing errors in processing logic after await resolves

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, promise, async-await

When using a `try/catch` for an `async/await` request, and a some logic needs to be performed on the result, where is the best place to do that logic? I have a function like this

```
function synchronousTransform (data) {
  return data.reduce( n => n * 2)
}
async function requestFn () {
  try {
    const myPromisedValue = await axios.get(url)
    const result = synchronousTransform(myPromisedValue.data)
    res.status(200).send(result)
  } catch (xhrError) {
    res.status(500).send(xhrError)
  } finally {
    console.log('done')
  }
}
```

It seems that something in `synchronousTransform` isn't working and I'm getting errors. However, the only thing I'm seeing thrown in the try/catch block is like it's a problem with the XHR. How can I isolate the functionality of `synchronousTransform` so that I can see the actual exceptions it's causing?

Comment: If there’s an error inside `synchronousTransform` it should be caught and stored in `xhrError` if your GET request is successful.

Comment: You can nest try-catch blocks?? Or simply resolve the bug...

Comment: _"It seems that something in `synchronousTransform` isn't working and I'm getting errors"_ If the issue is `synchronousTransform` why is code for `requestFn` included at Question and not full code of `synchronousTransform`?

Comment: @guest271314 because I'm sure I can easily debug that code once I understand a good pattern for how to unite async/await/try/catch with logic that needs to happen after ajax is successfully complete. why would i include it?

Comment: _"why would i include it?"_ Because you indicate at OP that the issue is at that portion of code _"How can I isolate the functionality of `synchronousTransform` so that I can see the actual exceptions it's causing?"_ What is the requirement?

Comment: @AndrewLi That's true, but then the try-catch is catching errors for potentially all sorts of things that might be happening in `synchronousTransform`. That seems a little unideal.

Comment: Note, another issue with code at Question is that no value is returned from `requestFn`

Comment: @guest271314 The only two questions here are `When using a try/catch for an async/await request, and a some logic needs to be performed on the result, where is the best place to do that logic?` and `How can I isolate the functionality of synchronousTransform so that I can see the actual exceptions it's causing?` There's nothing about resolving the bug in the omitted code. I'm not sure where your confusion is, but surely it's clear by now I'm not looking to crack a bug in an omitted function.

Comment: _"but surely it's clear by now I'm not looking to crack a bug in an omitted function"_ Then why omit the function from the Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @guest271314 I'm beginning to suspect you may just be trolling right now. Either way, I'm removing myself from this discussion. Cheers.

Comment: @1252748 _"I'm beginning to suspect you may just be trolling right now."_ No need to call this user out of name. Presently, the Question and expected result are not clear. Calling this user out of their name does not remedy the the lack of clarity at the Question.

Comment: _"However, the only thing I'm seeing thrown in the try/catch block is like it's a problem with the XHR."_ Then that needs to be addressed, `const result = synchronousTransform(myPromisedValue.data)` should not be reached if there is an error thrown at `const myPromisedValue = await axios.get(url)`

Comment: you need to post the the errors you get back. You also need to console.log the axios result to make sure its an actual array.

Answer (score 0):

You have `await` keyword on your first line, but not when calling `synchronousTransform`.

This means that potentially its execution can end after the response is sent and you're out of the try/catch part.

You left out the internal code of it, so can't say if it returns a promise or not, but it ahould have `await` when calling it.

Comment: ... but its clearly called _synchronous_Transform. If you're right its only more reason to close this question.

Comment: `synchronousTransform` is just performing a reduce on `data`; it doesn't return a promise, just a value.

Comment: `You left out the internal code of it, so can't say if it returns a promise or not, but it ahould have await when calling it.` => even if it is non-promise returning and a simple sync operation?

Comment: @MeirionHughes what was the initial reason?

Comment: @1252748 There is nothing wrong with your code; any error is caught. If the axios request fails, its caught and sent with 500 status. If you access the response data incorrectly, in the transform, its caught and send back to you. Your problem is the request is bad or the actual body you get back isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

> However, the only thing I'm seeing thrown in the try/catch block is
>   like it's a problem with the XHR.

Not certain how that is possible, `res.status(200).send(result)` should not be reached at code at Question. You can use `console.trace()` to get further data about an error.

The pattern substantially depends on how the error should be handled and what expected result is; that is if the error is expected to be handled within the first parameter to `.then()` or second parameter to `.then()` and `catch()`. That is a decision for the developer to make themselves, depending on the requirement of the application.

```js
function synchronousTransform (data) {
  // some code to reformat `data` that is not working
  throw new Error("synchronousTransform error")
}
async function fn() {
  let request;
  try {
    request = await Promise.resolve(1).then(synchronousTransform)
                    .catch(err => { console.error(err); throw err});
    console.log("tried"); // not called
  } catch(err) {
    console.error("caught again", err);
    request = err;
  } finally {
    // the error is handled by now
    console.log("finally");
  }
  
  return request;
}
fn()
.then(data => {
  if (data instanceof Error) {
    // trace the throw error
    console.trace("trace thrown error", data);
    throw data
  } else {
    // do stuff with data
  }
})
.catch(err => console.error("caught yet, again", err));
```

Comment: Note, if the actual XHR request is also an issue, that should issue can be addressed simultaneously to addressing decision as to how to handle possible errors at a subsequent function call that relies on response data from successful XHR request. Else, if the inquiry is not concerning handling both XHR and subsequent errors not sure what problem the inquiry is addressing.

Answer (score -1):

OP's issue is that "synchronousTransform" is supposed to throw an error, but fails silently because it is wrapped inside a try-catch block. This problem could be mitigated by simply taking "synchronousTransform" out of the immediate scope of the try-catch block.

```
function synchronousTransform (data)
{
  // some code to reformat `data` that is not working
}

async function requestFn()
{
    try
    {
        await new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
        {
            axios.get(url).then(function(myPromisedValue)
            {
                const result = synchronousTransform(myPromisedValue.data);
                res.status(200).send(result);
                resolve();

            }).catch(function(err)
            {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }
    catch (xhrError)
    {
        res.status(500).send(xhrError)
    }
    finally
    {
        console.log('done')
    }
}
```

Or better

```
async function requestFn()
{
    let myPromisedValue;

    try
    {
        myPromisedValue = await axios.get(url);
    }
    catch (xhrError)
    {
        res.status(500).send(xhrError);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myPromisedValue && myPromisedValue.data)
        {
            const result = synchronousTransform(myPromisedValue.data);
            res.status(200).send(result);
        }

        console.log('done');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry made a mistake. 'myPromisedValue' should be passed into the callback function since axios.get is no longer the awaited promise

Comment: Yep, I figured that's what was going on. This looks pretty good. I'll be interested to see if anyone else has any better ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I think I came up with a better idea. Can you check if the second one works?

Comment: The `finally` block will always execute. How will that work with the two `res.send`s? Though this saves a layer of indentation, I'm not sure it's better. But I'm new to this stuff, so not totally sure if that's a correct viewpoint.

Comment: An answer with no explanation can be improved significantly by explaining in words what the OP's original problem was and what you did to fix it.  People coming along after the fact have to do some sort of visual diff to figure out what you changed and there is no explanation for why.

Comment: Okay made another edit. The second res.send will only fire if myPromisedValue.data exists. You might also be able to check if myPromisedValue is undefined, but I'm not 100% sure that's what it becomes if the promise gets rejected.